# Powershell to count members of a large AD group that exceeds 5000 members

Tags: powershell

I am currently looking for a powershell script to give me a count of how many users are a member of the group. The issues that I am running into has to do with ADWS being only able to return 5000 objects at a time with a 5 minuet timeout. The AD group that I'm trying to get information from is fairly large probably around 400,000 users and I am not sure that I can return the data within that 5 minutes.

When the code below is ran I do get the error message "Get-ADGroupMember : The size limit for this request was exceeded"

```
$ADServer = Read-Host "Input Name of AD Server: "
$GroupName = Read-Host "Input Name of AD Group: "
$Users = Get-ADGroupMember -Server $ADServer -Identity $GroupName
Write-Host "$GroupName has " $Users.count " Members'
```

Comment: If you only want to count the members of one particular group, then you only need the AD group (via "Get-ADGroup") and count the DNs in property "member". The property "member" is not part of the default properties returned, therefore add it as argument to parameter "-Properties". See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-adgroup?view=win10-ps#example-2--get-a-group-by-sid